cloning wordpress site not shown the website main oages
After clone the WordPress website in cpanel the website main url shown sample page
after click the sample it shown main website but after redirect url it is not shown main page shown sample page !
I already purge and clean the cache files, but same issue
is there any valid solutions for this
I already purge and clean the cache files, but same issue
is there any valid solutions for this
